# What is the default SVG unit in CSS?

Tags: svg, units-of-measurement

I would like to convert a `transform` SVG attribute into a CSS `transform`. Here it is:

```
<g transform="translate(11.225 164)"/>
```

But CSS requires me to specify units. What is the correct unit to specify? Since it's supposed to be a library, **I don't know the `width`, `height` or `viewport`** of the `<svg>`. Thus I can't compute the `px` or so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default (user) unit is px.

> One px unit is defined to be equal to one user unit. Thus, a length of "5px" is the same as a length of "5".

Per the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#Units)